# Using Nest Client to load completion fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use Nest to populate the completion suggestion field into an index. After reading this [ElasticSearch blog post about implementing a completion field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/) I see you can have the following properties:

- array of inputs
- single output
- weight
- payload

I am assuming that to load this data into an index I need to include an entity on my search object that contains the above fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to finally load the completion field by creating several classes, and following the [FluentMappingFullExample](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs) unit test, specifically the following part:

```
                    .Completion(s=>s
                    .Name(p=>p.Name.Suffix("completion"))
                    .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    .MaxInputLength(20)
                    .Payloads()
                    .PreservePositionIncrements()
                    .PreserveSeparators()
                )
```

For my search type entity, I created a field called suggest and made it of type CompletionField.

```
 public class CompletionField
{
    public CompletionField()
    {
        Input = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Input { get; set; }
    //public string Output { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

After I loaded my entity from the db using dapper, I then looped over the results and loaded my completion field with the appropriate inputs that I wanted. I was then able to successfully call the suggest API and query on this data. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Having the same problem as you. How did you indexed the objects? Can you post your index query and search query? Thanks

Comment: your sample looks very much irrelevant. I cant find any connection. when you index the Completion you are not defining its type as CompletionField. What for are you using the completionField? I guess you wanted to or your should have done something like this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example#part-5-suggestions