# How to index an object with completion fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Following http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

How can I **index**/**insert** (I can do mapping) an object using Nest client library to be able to provide following options:

```
"input": ...,
"output": ...,
"payload" : ...,
"weight" : ...
```

I would like to be able to provide multiple values in 'input' option.
Can't find anyway of doing this using NEST.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEST provides the [SuggestField](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/Domain/Suggest/SuggestField.cs) type in order to assist in indexing completion suggestions.  You don't necessarily need to use this type, you can provide your own that contains the expected completion fields (`input`, `output`, etc...), but the purpose of `SuggestField` is to make the whole process easier by already providing a baked in type.

**Usage:**

Add a suggest field to the document/type you are indexing:

```
public class MyType
{
    public SuggestField Suggest { get; set; }
}
```

Your mapping should look something like:

```
client.Map<MyType>(m => m
    .Properties(ps => ps
        .Completion(c => c.Name(x => x.Suggest).Payloads(true))
    )
);
```

Indexing example:

```
var myType = new MyType
{
    Suggest = new SuggestField
    {
        Input = new [] { "Nevermind", "Nirvana" },
        Output = "Nirvana - Nevermind",
        Payload = new { id = 1234 },
        Weight = 34
    }
};

client.Index<MyType>(myType);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this next week. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Hi Greg. It seems SuggestField.Input is string, not an array of strings. I would like to provide multiple inputs. Is it yet a not implemented feature in Nest?

Comment: I know I can copy the model from Nest and just change Input to be array of strings instead of a string and it will probably work. Can't accept your answer though as it is only partially correct.

Comment: Indeed, Input should be an array.  Just opened https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1220 so we can fix that.  Creating your own type would definitely work.

Comment: Just to let you know it worked using my variation of SuggestField with Input as an array =]

Comment: The input array example is visible here as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785425/using-nest-client-to-load-completion-fields-in-elasticsearch