# NEST / Elastic Search Auto-Completion 'Field [suggest] is not a completion suggest field'

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, nest

In between projects, started to play around with Elastic Search and NEST in preparation for some auto-completion features coming up.

I followed examples here and in the various docs ... and it *seems* like what I have should work. There must be some subtle difference with what i am doing.

This is the object that represents my document.

```
    [ElasticType(IdProperty="KeyInstn")]
public class Instn
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "keyinstn", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.Integer)]
    public int KeyInstn { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "name", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "ticker", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Ticker { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "street", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "city", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "state", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "zip", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "country", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "suggest", Type = FieldType.Completion)]
    public CompletionField Suggest { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that I use to create my index:

```
            var index = client.CreateIndex("snl", c => c
                .NumberOfReplicas(1)
                .NumberOfShards(5)
                .Settings(s => s
                    .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                    .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
                )
                .AddMapping<Instn>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()
                        .Properties(props => props
                            .Completion(s => s
                                .Name(p => p.Suggest)
                                .IndexAnalyzer("simple")
                                .SearchAnalyzer("simple")
                                .MaxInputLength(20)
                                .Payloads()
                                .PreservePositionIncrements()
                                .PreserveSeparators()
                            )
                        )
                ));
```

I am populating my documents using IndexMany in batches of 1000 documents.

I then perform my query:

```
            var suggestResponse = this._client.Suggest<Instn>(s => s
        .Index("snl")
        .Completion("suggest", c => c
            .Text(this.AutoCompleteText.Text)
            .OnField("suggest")));
```

The error I receive is:

Field [suggest] is not a completion suggest field

Using SENSE, I pulls the mappings and notice that "suggest" doesn't have a type. The examples I followed indicate that the type should be 'completion.:'

[Elasticsearch - Autocomplete with NEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677298/elasticsearch-autocomplete-with-nest)

```
    {
   "snl": {
      "mappings": {
         "instn": {
            "properties": {
               "city": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "country": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "keyinstn": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "state": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "suggest": {
                  "properties": {
                     "input": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "output": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "payload": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "weight": {
                        "type": "double"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "zip": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In place of the CompletionObject I created myself, I also tried the intrinsic object, "SuggestField."

If anyone could point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong, I'd appreciate it. FWIW "normal" searches work fine and return appropriate results.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1/26/2016**

So, managed to get an index created that looks "better" ... I was able to get around the new error "analyzer on completion field must be set when search_analyzer is set" by omitting the search analyzer during creation and now my index looks like this:

```
        {
   "snl": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "instn": {
            "properties": {
               "city": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "country": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "keyinstn": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "state": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "suggest": {
                  "properties": {
                     "completion": {
                        "properties": {
                           "field": {
                              "type": "string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "input": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "output": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "payload": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "text": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "weight": {
                        "type": "double"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "zip": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1453835225862",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "90QKK1OyRMKtwcyjAwPElA",
            "version": {
               "created": "2010199"
            }
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

However, no completion searches return any results. Is it because the search analyzer omission? If so, how do I get around the "analyzer on completion field must be set when search_analyzer is set" error?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785425/using-nest-client-to-load-completion-fields-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Actually, I tried even the example cited in my text, above and saw the response:

"analyzer on completion field [suggest] must be set when search_analyzer is set"

I receive this response with my code and the example code.

Comment: May you post your query?

Comment: var suggestResponse = this._client.Suggest<Instn>(s => s
            .Index("snl")
            .Completion("instn-suggest", c => c
                .Text(this.AutoCompleteText.Text)
                .OnField("suggest")));

Comment: @MikeWright In the update, the suggest mapping still doesn't look correct - `suggest` has been mapped as an object and not as a `completion suggester` field. You'll need to create a new index with this field. Could you log the requests and responses to ES using similar code in the linked question? Also, what version of ES and what version of NEST are you using?